# How to export an svg icon in adobe illustrator with gaussian blur?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, export, blur

How to export an svg icon in adobe illustrator with gaussian blur?

I am working with Adobe illustratot CC. When I use "effekt - svg filter - AI Gauscherweichzeichner 4 or 7" doesen`t work. When I open the icon on the pc or in the browser it has no blur effekt.

With "effekt - Weichzeichnungsfilter - Gausian Weichzeichner" it work. But I am not sure it is the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting your artwork and using **Object > Expand Appearance**. I created a simple vector object and exported it to SVG after using that option. It rendered with the Gaussian blur I applied when dropped into Chrome and Safari for Mac.

Comment: looks good, thx dugost!